# Посчитать количество месяцев от одной даты dateFrom к другой выбранной дате dateTo

Tags: java

Всем привет! 
Я чет наглухо отрубился и не понимаю как посчитать количество месяцев между двумя датами...help!!
[image: <code>Код</code>]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dt7g.png)

```
        int countMotnh = 0;
        Calendar startC = Calendar.getInstance();
        startC.setTime(dateFrom);
        Calendar endC = Calendar.getInstance();
        endC.setTime(dateTo);
```

Буду благодарен, если поможете, потому что я вообще не могу понять!
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А сколько месяцев между 29 февраля и 1 марта? А между 1 марта и 31 марта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я нигде не ошибся, то в `countMonths` будет точное кол-во месяцев (с учётом текущего месяца) между датами. Порядок дат не важен.

```
Calendar startC = Calendar.getInstance();
startC.setTime(dateFrom);
Calendar endC = Calendar.getInstance();
endC.setTime(dateTo);


int years = Math.abs(startC.get(Calendar.YEAR) - endC.get(Calendar.YEAR));
int countMonths;

if ( years > 0 ) {

    int months;

    if ( endC.getTimeInMillis() > startC.getTimeInMillis() )
        months = endC.get(Calendar.MONTH) + (12 - startC.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    else months = startC.get(Calendar.MONTH) + (12 - endC.get(Calendar.MONTH));

    countMonths = (years-1)*12 + months;

}
else if ( endC.getTimeInMillis() > startC.getTimeInMillis() )
    countMonths = endC.get(Calendar.MONTH) - startC.get(Calendar.MONTH);
else
    countMonths = startC.get(Calendar.MONTH) - endC.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь!)

Answer (score 0):

Переведите обе даты в миллисекунды. Получите разницу и высчитайте потом из них количество месяцев.

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь!)

Answer (score 0):

Можно считать от сегодняшний даты в количестве дней

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            long timeUp = format.parse(DateActivation).getTime();
            long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeUp;
            long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Или

```
LocalDate futureDate = LocalDate.now().plusMonths(12);
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь!)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(LocalDate.parse("2020-01-31")
.withDayOfMonth(1), LocalDate.parse("2020-03-29").withDayOfMonth(1)));
```

В одну, но длинную строчку ))